# Problemas para usar JAVA en R versión 3.5.0 y RStudio versión 1.1.423 con paquetes rJava y coreNLP

Tags: java, r, rstudio, jni, rjava

Hace unos días descargué una nueva versión de R.

R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

y una nueva versión de Rstudio Version 1.1.423

Al querer utilizar los paquetes de rJava y coreNLP con Rstudio no los puedo usar. Al cargar la librería de rJava esto es lo que se muestra en pantalla:

```
> library("rJava", 
lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 
  '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/
  rJava.so':  
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/
  rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/
libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: 
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/
libs/rJava.so
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib: 
mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libclient.dylib 
: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Mi sistema operativo es MAC OS X Sierra 10.12.6.

Al ver que no funcionaba java con R, instale la actualización de java  8 versión 171 y reinicie la máquina. Traté de usar de nueva cuenta rJava y coreNLP y me arrojó el mismo error.

Después de ello, instalé java para macOS 2017-001 que instala el antiguo Java 6 runtime para macOS 10.13 High Sierra, macOS 10.12 Sierra, macOS 10.11 El Capitan, macOS 10.10 Yosemite, macOS 10.9 Mavericks, macOS 10.8 Mountain Lion y macOS 10.7 Lion que obtuve de:

```
https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=es_ES
```

Posterior a ello de nueva cuenta reinicie la máquina y traté de cargar rJava y coreNLP y de nueva cuenta me arrojó el mismo error que se menciona arriba. Busqué alguna posible solución en internet y encontré que debía ejecutar el siguiente comando desde la terminal de mi Mac:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Lo hice y me arroja el siguiente error sobre un archivo **jni.h**:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Juan:~ juancarlos$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Password:
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java 
Java version     : 1.6.0_65
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : 
detected JNI linker flags : - 
L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries -ljvm
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   - 
I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

No soy ingeniero en sistemas y mis conocimiento de informática son limitados. Alguien me podría ayudar a explicarme que significa este error y como puedo solucionarlo para que pueda utilizar java en R?

Comment: El primer error que indicas, pareciera ser que la arquitectura de JAVA no es la adecuada para la versión de R, podría ser el caso que tuvieras un  JAVA de 32 bits versus un R de 64? desconozco si esto es posible en MAC. El otro error, ya lo he sufrido al menos en Linux. R al instalar paquetes en SOs distintos de Windows, lo que hace es descargar el código fuente y tratar de compilarlo. En tu caso no ha podido hacerlo, por que no pudo encontrar  una de las cabeceras .h necesarias (jni.h). Trata de buscar este archivo, si no existe, es que falta instalar el JDK

Comment: Si el archivo jni.h existe, tal vez el problema sea en la variable `JAVA_HOME` que este apuntando a otra instalación sin el JDK. El objetivo sería hacer que R encuentre el archivo jni.h (y cualquier otro que llegue a necesitar) para que pueda completar la compilación del paquete. Te dejo este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562160/r-cmd-javareconf-not-finding-jni-h, tal vez te sirva.

Comment: Hola Patricio. Al final des-nstalé el ambiente Java, rJava y coreNLP. Posteriormente instale de nueva cuenta Java versión jre-8u171, instalé la versión jdk-8u171 del kit de desarrolladores e instalé rJava y coreNLP. Una vez hecho esto cargué las librerias en R y ya funcionaron bien

Comment: estupendo, usaste el segundo secreto de la gente de sistemas: desinstalar/instalar, (el primero es apagar y prender) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

En la siguiente página de github encontré los pasos para instalar un kit de desarrolladores de java más reciente, la versión 6 de java de apple para Mac OS X Sierra y la librería de rJava:

```
https://github.com/MTFA/CohortEx/wiki/Run-rJava-with-RStudio-under-OSX- 
10.10,-10.11-(El-Capitan)-or-10.12-(Sierra)
```

Me parece que el problema era que la versión de jdk que tenía instalada en mi Mac era muy vieja y ya no era compatible con la librería de rJava y coreNLP
Después de instalar todo conforme a los pasos provistos ya funciona rJava y coreNLP.